# Strange I18n date output with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, localization, internationalization

I've got a strange problem with date translations in my Ruby On Rails 3 application, and I really don't understand why...

Here are my `en.yml` and `fr.yml` :

```
fr:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
      short: "%e %b"
      long: "%e %B %Y" 
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S"
      short: "%d %b %H:%M"
      long: "%A %d %B %Y %H:%M"
    am: 'am'
    pm: 'pm'



en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
      short: "%b %d"
  time:
    am: am
    formats:
      default: ! '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
      long: ! '%B %d, %Y %H:%M'
      short: ! '%d %b %H:%M'
    pm: pm
```

This is not specific to a particuliar view, but for instance in one of my view :

```
<td><%=l job_application.created_at, :format => :default %></td>
```

I get those strange outputs :

```
With locale = :en
=> t, 30 o 2012 18:09:33 +0000

With locale = :fr
=> 30 o 2012 18:09:33
```

Where do these wrong "formats" come from ?

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 (with Postgresql / gem pg), and **everything related to I18n works fine except for dates**.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Yes I have too... (post updated)

Comment: The output matches the format strings for times except that the string parts are getting truncated to one character? Any idea where the `o` comes from? What should the formatted versions be?

Comment: Well not exactly, the single character is not always the first letter of the month or the day name. For instance : Mon, 01 Oct 2012 17:11:55 UTC +00:00 will be translated to : "01 n 2012 17:11:55"

Comment: What happens if you manually use those formats with `strftime`?

Comment: It works fine with strftime...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I've finally figured this out, sorry for taking so long.

The Rails `l` helper just calls `I18n.localize`. If you trace through the `I18n.localize` code, you'll end up [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb#L59):

```
format = format.to_s.gsub(/%[aAbBp]/) do |match|
  case match
  when '%a' then I18n.t(:"date.abbr_day_names",                  :locale => locale, :format => format)[object.wday]
  when '%A' then I18n.t(:"date.day_names",                       :locale => locale, :format => format)[object.wday]
  when '%b' then I18n.t(:"date.abbr_month_names",                :locale => locale, :format => format)[object.mon]
  when '%B' then I18n.t(:"date.month_names",                     :locale => locale, :format => format)[object.mon]
  when '%p' then I18n.t(:"time.#{object.hour < 12 ? :am : :pm}", :locale => locale, :format => format) if object.respond_to? :hour
  end
end
```

So the `localize` helper doesn't use `strftime` for the "stringy" parts of the date/time, it tries to do it by itself. Add the translations (as arrays in your YAML) for the month and day names as above and your localized dates and times should start working.

If you don't have those translation arrays in your YAML, then `I18n.t(:"date.abbr_month_names")` will give you strings like this:

```
"translation missing: en.date.abbr_month_names"
```

and then `I18n.localize` will end up doing silly things like this:

```
"translation missing: en.date.abbr_month_names"[10]
```

That will use [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) instead of the expected [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) and you end up with random looking single character month and day names.

Comment: I found the problem thanks to your answer ! Actualy, I had all the "date.abbr_day_names" / "date.abbr_month_names" / ... keys in my translation files, but I had  overridden the "date" key to translate the "date" word (global key without namespace) ! Not very clever I know... Thanks for your time !

Comment: "Add the translations (as arrays in your YAML) for the month and day names as above and your localized dates and times should start working." What? Where? I'm sorry I don't get this, could someone provide an example please?

Answer (score 1):

> Where do these wrong "formats" come from ?

Because `created_at` is a DateTime, rails using `time` formats (not `date`).

https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml#L195

```
time:
  am: am
  formats:
    default: ! '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

Answer (score 0):

Type in your console

```rb
I18n.t(:"date")
```

to check if you are getting the translations you defined in your translation `.yml` file.

Compare the structure with the standard EN locale

```rb
I18n.t(:"date", locale:'en')
```

That made me notice I was declaring the `date:` attribute twice in my `.yml`, and the first part was being overwritten by the second declaration.

You should get the `abbr_month_names` that you declared when calling

```rb
I18n.t(:"date.abbr_month_names")
```

These are the ones that will be used when calling `%b`.

If not, check your locale `.yml` file to make sure they are properly declared, and not being declared twice.

You may also call `I18n.locale` to check if the `.yml` file you are editing is the one being used by rails