# rails localization of date format gives unexpected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localization

For some reason `I18n.localize(DateTime)` is not returning what i expect
it to. for example:

```
 I18n.localize(Date.today, :format => '%b')
   => "d"

 Date.today.strftime('%b')
   => "Jul"
```

Why is `:format => '%b'` returning `d` instead of `Jul`?

Edit: Rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9

Comment: Is this the same thing as http://stackoverflow.com/q/12664062/479863 ?

Comment: i think so! @muistooshort if you post this as your answer i'd be happy to give you credit

Comment: Or we can just mark it as a duplicate to (hopefully) funnel everyone to the existing answer.

Comment: works for me. i voted to close as a dupe.