# What does this do in de.yml? date: <<: *datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

I've had a strange error where single characters appear instead of full weekday representations when utilizing the I18n.localize method.

[This answer clarified a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20839490/3205492), and helped me to inserted the correct translations.

But other error messages about missing translations appeared until I removed the following:

```
date:
  <<: *datetime
time:
  <<: *datetime
```

Do I need those though? What is their purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need this. It places `datetime` fragment to `date` and `time`.

Here is an example:

```
defaults: &defaults
  a: b

c:
  <<: *defaults
d:
  <<: *defaults
```

is same as

```
c:
  a: b
d:
  c: b
```

Comment: What does this mean? Is `datetime` dependent of this or the other way around?

Comment: OK, so `<<: *defaults` ensures that  `c` and `d` in this case inherits whatever keys are defined in `defaults`?

Comment: Yes, it's something like partials

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation! I wish this was better documented.